# Print the pieces of 2 dimensional rod cutting that we get after the optimal cut

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Declaring the variables and the arrays

```
int cost[1000][1000];
int d[1000][1000];
int cutPrice;

bool cut_is_vertical[1000][1000];
int max_index[1000][1000];
int n, m;
```

This function print is for printing the pieces

```
void print(int n, int m) {
if (max_index[n][m] == 0) {
    cout << n << m <<" ";
    return;
}
print(max_index[n][m]);
print(n - max_index[n][m]);

}
```

this is the main program to cut vertically and horizontally:

```
int main()
{
cin >> n >> m >> cutPrice;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j){
        cin >> cost[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    d[i][0] = 0;
}
for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
    d[0][j] = 0;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
        // Do not cut.
        d[i][j] = cost[i][j];
        max_index[i][j] = 0;
```

This is for cutting horizontally

```
for (int k = 1; k <= i / 2; ++k) {
            if (d[i][j] < d[k][j] + d[i - k][j] - cutPrice) {
                max_index[i][j] = k;
                cut_is_vertical[i][j] = false;
                d[i][j] = d[k][j] + d[i - k][j] - cutPrice;
            }
        }
```

This is for cutting vertically.

```
for (int k = 1; k <= j / 2; ++k) {
            if (d[i][j] < d[i][k] + d[i][j - k] - cutPrice) {
                max_index[i][j] = k;
                cut_is_vertical[i][j] = true;
                d[i][j] = d[i][k] + d[i][j - k] - cutPrice;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << d[n][m] << endl;
print(n, m);
return 0;
```

}

the errors that gives me is at the print function which are:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'void print(int, int)'
   print(max_index[n][m]);
                   ^

 note: declared here
 void print(int n, int m) {
      ^

 error: too few arguments to function 'void print(int, int)'
  print(n - max_index[n][m]);
                           ^

 note: declared here
 void print(int n, int m) {
      ^
```

Can you please pin point me where is the mistake in my print function thanks

Comment: Which part of that error is unclear? Your function takes two parameters, but you only supply one

Comment: What is actually unclear about that error message? You are passing only a single argument where the `print()` function expects two. Also your question title doesn't have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Error message is explicity telling you WHAT is the error and WHERE is it. Just read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call function that way:

```
print(n, m);
```

instead of:

```
print(max_index[i][j]);
```

Your function takes two arguments as error message is telling you.